# Authorize and access Google Tasks API from Android app?

Tags: android, oauth, google-tasks-api

I'm trying to add support for Google Tasks to my app -- specifically, the app should be able to add a new tasks.

I've spent most of this week trying to accomplish this without success. Specifically, I've not managed to get my app fully authorized to access the API. I've found 3-5 different tutorials or sets of documentation for how to do it:

- https://developers.google.com/google-apps/tasks/oauth-and-tasks-on-android
- https://google-api-client-libraries.appspot.com/documentation/tasks/v1/java/latest/index.html
- https://developers.google.com/google-apps/tasks/instantiate
- http://developer.android.com/google/play-services/auth.html
- http://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/gms/auth/GoogleAuthUtil.html
- http://code.google.com/p/google-api-java-client/wiki/OAuth2

Many of the above appear to contradict one another, or at least use different APIs whose overlap isn't immediately apparent to me. The closest I've come is via the sample code referenced in the first link above (http://bit.ly/UHTKNW). I can get that to compile and run, and even to request permission from the user to access Tasks, as expected. But it then fails with a 403 Forbidden "access not configured" exception. I'm presuming I need to supply an API Key and/or client secret, but the APIs used in the example don't appear to provide an obvious way to do that. I'm also not clear on whether I need to set up a signing certificate fingerprint to make this work, and if so how to go about doing that.

So I'm stuck, confused, and super-frustrated. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks.
--Dave

Answer (score 3):

Those APIs have changed a lot, I can understand your frustration.

Check out the [most recent sample application](http://samples.google-api-java-client.googlecode.com/hg/tasks-android-sample/instructions.html). It contains the instructions for setting up the API access and getting you started.

Basically, you just register your application in the API Console and your code doesn't have to deal with any API keys:

```
GoogleAccountCredential credential = GoogleAccountCredential.usingOAuth2(context, TasksScopes.TASKS);
credential.setSelectedAccountName(accountName);

mService = new com.google.api.services.tasks.Tasks.Builder(new NetHttpTransport(), new GsonFactory(), credential)
        .setApplicationName("YourApplicationName").build();
```

The Task APIs may throw different Exceptions, e.g. when the user has to confirm your app's access. In the sample, the [`CommonAsyncTask`](http://code.google.com/p/google-api-java-client/source/browse/tasks-android-sample/src/main/java/com/google/api/services/samples/tasks/android/CommonAsyncTask.java?repo=samples) deals with them.

Comment: This is the sample code I've been using but haven't gotten to work yet. I'd left the application name as Google had it and could change it to the one displayed in the API Console...is that really sufficient to authenticate me? And in the API Console itself, there are numerous setup options requiring different sorts of information; what's the correct setup there?

Comment: @DaveFeldman Did you create a Client ID for OAuth access? I believe it's the big blue button under API Access. Don't use Simple API Access, that's the wrong one. I don't think the application name is used for authentication, you have to enter your package name and signing certificate fingerprint for the Client ID. Please check the instruction in the link I posted again, the steps under "Register Your Application" are pretty detailed.

Answer (score 0):

check my other answer [Access youtube account with accountmanager](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12841352/access-youtube-account-with-accountmanager/12841485#12841485)

it's for the YouTube, but the difference is just a matter of passing the right "link" to the code. Hope it helps.