# Using Google+ Sign-In to authenticate for YouTube Data APIs on Android

Tags: youtube-api, google-plus, android-youtube-api, youtube-data-api

I am a newbie at the Android development environment. I am trying to write an app the uses YouTube Data API, and I need to pass in the Users credentials to the youtube API:

```
credential = getAccountCredential(); //Get The Account Credentials
final HttpTransport httpTransport = AndroidHttp.newCompatibleTransport();
final JsonFactory jsonFactory = GsonFactory.getDefaultInstance();       
youtube = new YouTube.Builder(httpTransport, jsonFactory, credential).setApplicationName(
"myAppName").build();

com.google.api.services.youtube.YouTube.Videos.List videoRequest = youtube.videos().list("contentDetails");
videoRequest.setChart("mostPopular");
VideoListResponse channelResult = videoRequest.execute();
```

Reading the [Android OAuth 2.0 documentation](https://developers.google.com/accounts/docs/OAuth2InstalledApp), it recommends using the [Google+ Sign-In](https://developers.google.com/+/mobile/android/sign-in) to authenticate the users. However, I can't find an easy way to use the Google+'s constructed GoogleApiClient to GoogleAccountCredential that the YouTube APIs accept (How do I implement getAccountCredential() in the code above if I'm using Google+ Sign-in). Any help would be highly appreciated.

Comment: its not exactly what you need, but this answer should help you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12841352/access-youtube-account-with-accountmanager