# Youtube v3 api login android

Tags: android, api, authentication, youtube

I cant find anything related to the login in here: https://developers.google.com/youtube/android/player/reference/com/google/android/youtube/player/package-summary

I want to subscribe to channels from my android app, so I guess I need to logged in the user to his youtube account, how can I do that? Or should I use the google sign in: 
https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/android/

Thanks for the guidance,

Comment: try this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12841352/access-youtube-account-with-accountmanager