# Add YouTube data api to Google Client Api on android

Tags: youtube-data-api, android-youtube-api

How do I create a YouTube API class that I can pass on to the GoogleApiClient builder?

```
 mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(getActivity())
                .addApi(Plus.API)
                .addApi(null)//<========================================INSERT YOUTUBE API HERE
                .addScope(Plus.SCOPE_PLUS_LOGIN)
                .addScope(Plus.SCOPE_PLUS_PROFILE)
                .addScope(CustomScopes.VIEW_YOUTUBE)
                .addConnectionCallbacks(this)
                .addOnConnectionFailedListener(this)
                .build();
```

Comment: you mean by logging, by google client api

Comment: @Shawon I mean how can I create an API class for youtube data and add it to the googleapiclient. Same way I add the Plus.API , I want to add an API object for Youtube but I don't know how to create one.

Comment: its not exactly what you need, but this answer should help you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12841352/access-youtube-account-with-accountmanager